# ASP.Net Ajax TextBox Enter Key Click Go to server

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a textbox i need to go to the server when Enter Key is clicked with ajax to update a label on the page

Answer (score 0):

if you call a javascript function something along the lines of

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 function HandleKeyPress(sender, eventArgs)
{
    if (eventArgs.get_domEvent().keyCode == 13)
    {
        b//call method here to do what you want on enter button press
    }
}
```

this may help you on the way to finding what you want to do

Comment: Thanks paul for your reply
but what i ment that i need inside your If statement to write code to go to the server and bring databack to update a textbox , i don't know how yet??

Comment: i think what you need to do is to figure out what your trying to call and then explore the use of jQuery to call a service - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - then work out what you want to happen.